# How to keep working and making new PR on one branch in Github

Tags: git, github

My current workflow is like:

1. Create a new branch say `branch_a` and edit code.
2. PR `branch_a`.
   if successfully merged, delete `branch_a` -> pull from master and create a new branch and keep working.
   if merge failed, go back to local and create another `branch_b` from `branch_a`. Repeat this process(creating new branch) until successfully merged.

So, I wonder is there a more sufficient workflow that allows me to keep working on one branch(e.g. `branch_a`). In other words, whether PR is successful or not, I can continue work on the branch and make 'new' PR with this branch. (Because if I make changes to the branch and commit to the remote, there will be new 'PR' popup for me to create new PR.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using github and are creating a PR (pull request), you should have a fork of the repo you are looking to contribute to. Your code changes should only be in your fork, within a branch in that fork. You make changes/commit to your fork's branch. Those changes automatically show in your PR (the PR takes the diff of the upstream/master(or branch) and your fork/branch.

Comment: @m_vemuri No, there's no need to have a fork just to make pull requests.

Comment: It sounds like Xinyu doesn't have write permissions to the repo and wants to create a branch. For that you do need a fork.

Comment: @m_vemuri It doesn't sound like that at all. It sounds like an ordinary git flow.

Comment: @m_vemuri I am not using the fork workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if merge failed, go back to local and create another branch_b from branch_a. Repeat this process(creating new branch) until successfully merged.

If the merge "failed" because the PR partner asks you to do some more work, this is arguably wrong. Do not make a new branch. Just keep committing and pushing on `branch_a`. The commits are automatically made part of the same PR.

> So, I wonder is there a more sufficient workflow that allows me to keep working on one branch(e.g., branch_a). In other words, whether PR is successful or not, I can continue work on the branch and make 'new' PR with this branch.

Yes, that's what I just described. If not successful, stay on that branch and keep working and pushing and getting reviewed until it *is* successful. That *is* the standard PR workflow.

Meanwhile, to make a *new* feature branch based on `branch_a`, *that* is when you make `branch_b` off of `branch_a`. However:

- In general this can be risky, because now as `branch_a` changes you are apt to lose touch with the changes; you need to keep merging (or rebasing) from time to time.
- There is another possible argument against this whole idea: you are effectively trying to sneak the first PR into your second PR before the first PR has been approved. It is better for PRs to be independent of one another. If they cannot be, they should not have been different PRs to begin with (at least, that is one school of thought).

Comment: thanks for the illustration on the scenario it failed. Once the PR is approve, should I keep working on the same branch(pull from master and rebase) or should I create a new branch instead?

Comment: Long-lived feature branches are usually a big mistake, as they invite merge conflicts later. It's better to throw away a merged branch and start a new one.